# ¿Por qué me da error en este código de unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy siguiendo los pasos de un tutorial, pero me da este error y al tipo del tutorial no le marca nada.

Éste es en Unity:

[image: Este es en Unity]

Aquí está el código en MonoDevelop (este código hace que rote un objeto)

[image: Aquí está el código en MonoDevelop]

Answer (score 6):

El error se debe a que estás asignando un valor a un objeto recién creado:

```
new Vector3(2f, 20f, 2f) = Time.deltaTime; // No se puede asignar un valor a un objeto
```

Esa es una asignación incorrecta.

Probablemente lo que quieres hacer es multiplicar esos valores:

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(2f, 20f, 2f) * Time.deltaTime);
```

Puedes encontrar más información en la [documentación](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) de Unity.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, efectivamente ese era mi error.

Comment: Hola @JorgeAnza, si esta respuesta te ayudó puedes votarla positivamente y marcarla como aceptada.